# What is the full phrase painted over on the ground and its purpose?

Tags: plot-explanation, man-of-steel, dc-extended-universe

In *Man of Steel*, when Clark surrenders to the US army and is sitting in the interrogation room at 01:10:55 you can see words "hind the line", which I assume comes from "behind the line", but the rest of the phrase is painted over.

What do you think is the full phrase and the reason behind painting over it?

[image: ... HIND THE LINE]

Comment: ed-ta, I think this question needs to be rephrased to be relevant. The most obvious answer would be "detainees must stay behind the line" or something to that effect. It's a police station and there's a line on the floor, so there's no real reason that it would say anything else. But a more on-topic question might be *why it was painted over, and if this was a deliberate choice by the filmmakers.*

Comment: If you know what was written then you can guess why it was painted over. And thanks for editing.

Comment: Unfortunately, if all you want is what the phrase is, that's off topic, so it's good that the question was edited... otherwise, it'd be closed.

Comment: It has already been pointed out, no need to repeat and try making people feel that a favour has been bestowed upon them. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it was relevant only at that particular moment. It was an expression of humans' attitude towards Clark. Just like criminals who are not accepted as 'normal' members of a society and stay behind bars in prisons or lines in this particular case, and treated differently from the rest of the society, Clark was also a stranger, an alien whose intentions or nature wasn't fully understood, so seeing 'behind the line' phrase behind Clark bears that symbolism in my opinion. So you can guess that he would be handed over to Zod.

Also note - if we continue our analogy with criminals - that he hasn't been tried/appeared before a judge yet. People see him later in action, and he is judged by his actions, and afterwards accepted as an ally i.e. acquitted.

And the reason it was painted over maybe because the rest of the phrase was irrelevant, and also if it said detainees - he is not really a detainee, wasn't detained, he surrendered. Or maybe because they couldn't really detain him, he ripped handcuffs off with ease.